# How To Access URLs Of Videos Uploaded Via Youtube Direct Lite

Tags: youtube-api

I am planning on integrating YouTube into my web app where users will be able to upload videos to YouTube.  I will need to programmatically access the URLs for all uploaded videos, the user IDs of the users who uploaded the videos, and record them in my database.

How can I do this using YouTube Direct Lite?

Is it possible to...

- have YouTube Direct Lite callback my app when the download has been completed?
- save parameters along with the uploaded video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. You can retrieve a feed of videos that have been submitted to your playlist using the Data API, just like YouTube Direct Lite does behind the scenes. The relevant API call is something like

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&orderby=published&category=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com%2Fschemas%2F2007%2Fkeywords.cat%7Dytdl`PLAYLISTID`

where `PLAYLISTID` is the id of the playlist you're using to solicit videos (omit the `PL` prefix).

You can periodically make this query from your own app to get a feed of videos that are being submitted.

Alternatively, you can use [YouTube Direct](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct/) instead of [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/). YouTube Direct is a full Java App Engine web application, and has its own datastore that gets updated whenever a submission happens. You can use that data however you'd like. It's a lot more work to get up and running with YouTube Direct, though.